# Addresses Port-Expander PCF8574

Tags: arduino

my port expander PCF8574 got the I2C Adress 0x38.
can someone tell me the Adresses of Port4 and Port5?

datasheet -> http://www.waveshare.com/wiki/PCF8574_IO_Expansion_Board

Answer (score 0):

According to the datasheet you should be writing a byte with the bit set corresponding to your exapansion port. So if you want to set Port4 and Port 5 you should be writing a byte to the I2C wit bits 4 and 5 high. Ex:

```
Wire.beginTransmission(0x38);
Wire.write(b00110000);
Wire.endTransmission();
```

4th and 5th bits are sent high. Send 0s to pull it low. you should also read carefully the datasheet for all the subtleties.